# Wordpress custom post type structure

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

i am building a wordpress website for a client. i need to build 1 template type of page with a list of fields that the client can fill in to populate the page. so lets say i build a template page called Person Template. On it i have an empty picture placeholder on the left and an empty Name Field below that. On the right i have an empty "persons phone number" and "Persons email" field.

what i need to create somehow is a system that the client can enter these 4 items into wp-admin somewhere and save that as a new Person. Then they can repeat and save another Person until they have created say 100 Person pages.

How do I do this? I tried building a Custom Post Type called Person CPT. I have built a Page called Person Template. I have built some "Person CPT" posts and put them on a page but i dont know how to create the Entry Fields page for my client to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that you'll need to use a custom post type. To add the fields you have two options:

1. Add the fields using `add_meta_box()`. You'll then need to save this data as post meta. Then in your `single-person.php` template you would retrieve the meta using `get_post_meta()`. It's a tad cumbersome, as you need to write the markup for the meta box, hook it into an action to add it to the admin page, and verify the content before it's saved. [Here's an article that walks you through it](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/)
2. Alternatively get yourself the [Advanced Custom Fields plugin:](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) it makes adding additional fields very quick and easy. I use it all the time.